# How do i get the full domain name in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, dns

I need to check my subdomain name (or if theres no subdomain) in asp.net. Right now i tested by adding s.localdev.com to my host files and use it to visit my asp.net page. Request.Url gives me localhost instead and RawUrl just gives me what is after the /. (Path and query i think its called). How do i get the full domain so i can check my sub domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.Url.Authority` Or `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)`

You might need to remove the `http(s)://` prefix.

Also look at `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

should do the trick